# Visual Studio Online открытие проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio, облако, vsto

Я только осваиваю разработку в облаке. Мне нужно иметь доступ к коду с разных компов под одной учётной записью. Воспользовался для этого инструментом Visual Studio Team Services. На рабочем компе загрузил код в облако, на домашнем компе пытаюсь подключиться к проекту и продолжить работу. С горем пополам клонировал репозиторий и вроде подгрузил файлы проекта, но поимел кучу ошибок и проект соответственно не компилится. [image: изображения]

Подскажите чайнику, что сделать чтобы спокойно осуществить задумку без особых танцев с бубном

Comment: Ты показываешь только список предупреждений, но ни одной ошибки компиляции. Тем не менее, выделенный тобой пункт как бы намекает на то, что далеко не все проекты есть на файловой системе. Возможно, ты забыл загрузить его в облако или скачать? Относительный путь с переходом на уровень выше (..) намекает на наличие какого-то проекта вне каталога солюшена. Забыл про него? Или склонировал неправильную папку из TFS?

Comment: а ошибок и нет, но не компилит. Я просто не очень понимаю.. файлы на облако заливались вроде все, и скачивались все. Но почему-то такой итог, чего-то не хватает

Comment: Почему то меня смущает строка с невозможностью открыть проект. Может у вас пути привязаны к старой системе? Существует ли у вас вообще директория "Класс для АПИ\net-api-wrapper" ? Проверьте файл .csproj, сделайте все пути относительно директории проекта. И советую не использовать русские названия в директориях проекта.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ посмотрел, директории этой и правда не оказалось на компе, на который загрузились файлы из репозитория. Но разве не должны ли файлы грузиться в облако ВСЕ, и загружаться оттуда ВСЕ?

Comment: @Antykus Это уже зависит от того - как загружали, как создавали проект итд. При загрузке смотрите раздел исключений, в нем может оказались ваши файлы.

Comment: @Antykus в TFS заливаются файлы, а не проект, если корнем репозитория ты выбрал папку солюшена, а один из проектов лежит каталогом выше, получишь такую вот ошибку